# Show/hide DIV based on radio button choice with use of jQuery

Tags: jquery

I asked this question before, *HOWEVER*; I am now able to assign names or ID's to the label radio buttons. I couldn't do this before and that made a mess of things. Various people tried to help, but I made a complete mess out of things (sorry).

The problem with WHMCS is that is very limited in editing things, when you think outside the box.

The radio buttons / labels are as described here:

```
<label id="{$options.nameonly}" name="{$options.nameonly}" >
    <input type="radio" name="configoption[{$configoption.id}]" value="{$options.id}"{if $configoption.selectedvalue eq $options.id} checked="checked"{/if} />
    {if $options.name}
    {$options.name}
    {else}
    {$LANG.enable}
    {/if}
</label>
```

Ignore the fact that I am using same ID and name twice. It's just to show I can name them both (this wasn't the case before). I am gonna remove one of them, depending what's best to use for this situation.

The variable, which is called {$options.nameonly}, can be various things which I have added through WHMCS.

Let's say {$options.nameonly} consists out of 3 possible options (radio buttons):

1. No backups at all
2. Weekly backups with professional backup
3. Monthly backups with professional backup

In this case label ID / name would be one of the above obviously.

Now I want to display a DIV based on any of the 3 above choices:

```
 - <div id="weeklymsg">Weekly backup information</div>
 - <div id="monthlymsg">Monthly backup information</div>
 - And don't show a DIV when 'No backups at all' option is selected
```

I tried several things to get this working, however the best I could achieve was making a DIV appear, but not disappear anymore.

I want to use **something similar** to this for my situation:

```
$("label[name='Weekly backups with professional backup']").click(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').parent().next('div').hide();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      var value = $(this).val();
        $('#'+value).fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#'+value).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

If you know a **better solution** or have a **better idea**, *please do share*.

I also don't know what is better in general; target the label ID or the label name? Or doesn't it matter that much?

If you need more information or details, please let me know. I already appreciate the fact that you are still reading this. :)

*Sidenote; in case you didn't notice it yet, ID/name will have spaces in between for example: "Weekly backups with professional backup"*

Update: added a simple JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0xpwg1h/).

**--------------------------------------------------------- UPDATE -----------------------------------------------------------**

Okay, to my best knowledge the problems are caused by "iradio_square-blue". For whatever reason this makes the DIV's not showing up when selecting an option.

I did a search through all files with textcrawler and found it also to be in .js file (twice).

First occassion is here:

```
jQuery('input').iCheck({
    inheritID: true,
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
    radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});
```

Second occassion is here:

```
jQuery.post("cart.php", 'a=cyclechange&ajax=1&i='+i+'&billingcycle='+billingCycle,
    function(data) {
        jQuery("#productConfigurableOptions").html(jQuery(data).find('#productConfigurableOptions').html());
        jQuery('input').iCheck({
            inheritID: true,
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
            increaseArea: '20%'
        });
    }
);
```

There were also some hits in the .css file related to "iradio_square-blue", however I don't think those are causing problems. But I do think the above 2 entries in the .js are causing issues with the DIV's?

***Added note:*** I am now pretty sure, those 2 parts in the base.js are causing the issues, because when I remove them (for testing) it works 100%. It shows and hides the DIV's. So anyone knows a workaround for this...?

Comment: is it possible to create fiddle to get a more clear picture.

Comment: Added a simple JSFiddle. Hope this helps a bit? And thank you for taking a look. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/r0xpwg1h/2/ is this what you expect ?

Comment: Well close; it starts with the both DIV's being displayed? I don't want them to show from start, only when one of the options is selected. Is this possible? Also I don't prefer to use the label name: "configoption[14]", because that's random in WHMCS. But probably that is something which can be changed, right?

Comment: Updated one with your suggesions.. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/r0xpwg1h/4/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solves your issues..

```js
$("#weeklymsg").hide();
$("#monthlymsg").hide();
$(".form-group input[type='radio']").on("change", function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "Monthly backups with professional backup"){
    $("#weeklymsg").hide();
            $("#monthlymsg").show();
    }else if($(e.target).closest("label")[0].id == "Weekly backups with professional backup"){
    $("#weeklymsg").show();
            $("#monthlymsg").hide();
    }else{
          $("#weeklymsg").hide();
            $("#monthlymsg").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputConfigOption14"></label>

            <div>
                <label for="inputConfigOption14">What kind of backups</label>
            </div><label class="" id="No backups at all"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style=" position: relative;">
                <label class="" id="No backups at all"><input name=
                "configoption[14]" type="radio" value="43"></label>No backups
                at all
            </div><label id="Weekly backups with professional backup"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="position: relative;">
                <label id=
                "Weekly backups with professional backup"><input name="configoption[14]"
                type="radio" value="43 "></label>Weekly backups with
                professional backup
            </div><label class="" id=
            "Monthly backups with professional backup"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style=">
                <label class="" id=
                "Monthly backups with professional backup"><input name=
                "configoption[14]" type="radio" value="43 "></label>Monthly
                backups with professional backup
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <br>

    <div id="weeklymsg">
        Weekly backup information
    </div>

    <div id="monthlymsg">
        Monthly backup information
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it works in JSFiddle, it doesn't work for some reason from within my website (based on WHMCS). It seems like to be a a JS/jQuery clash somewhere. But I understand it's impossible for you to fix this with the above example. Anyways I appreciate what you did and the answer works (at least for the JSFiddle). Will have to figure it out now to get it to work within WHMCS. :S

Comment: Please see the answer i have posted , it is done with pure javascript  !!

Answer (score 1):

Pure Javascript, I hope this solves your issue with WHMCS and jQuery..

```js
document.getElementById("weeklymsg").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("monthlymsg").style.display = "none";

var p = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group input[type='radio']");
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    p[i].onclick = function (e) {
        var closestStr = closest(e.target, "label").id;
        if (closestStr == "Monthly backups with professional backup") {
            document.getElementById("weeklymsg").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("monthlymsg").style.display = "block";
        } else if (closestStr == "Weekly backups with professional backup") {
            document.getElementById("weeklymsg").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("monthlymsg").style.display = "none";

        } else {
            document.getElementById("weeklymsg").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("monthlymsg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function closest(el, selector) {
    var matchesFn;
    // find vendor prefix
    ['matches', 'webkitMatchesSelector', 'mozMatchesSelector', 'msMatchesSelector', 'oMatchesSelector'].some(function (fn) {
        if (typeof document.body[fn] == 'function') {
            matchesFn = fn;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    // traverse parents
    while (el !== null) {
        parent = el.parentElement;
        if (parent !== null && parent[matchesFn](selector)) {
            return parent;
        }
        el = parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputConfigOption14"></label>

            <div>
                <label for="inputConfigOption14">What kind of backups</label>
            </div><label class="" id="No backups at all"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style=" position: relative;">
                <label class="" id="No backups at all"><input name=
                "configoption[14]" type="radio" value="43"></label>No backups
                at all
            </div><label id="Weekly backups with professional backup"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="position: relative;">
                <label id=
                "Weekly backups with professional backup"><input name="configoption[14]"
                type="radio" value="43 "></label>Weekly backups with
                professional backup
            </div><label class="" id=
            "Monthly backups with professional backup"></label>

            <div class="iradio_square-blue" style="style=">
                <label class="" id=
                "Monthly backups with professional backup"><input name=
                "configoption[14]" type="radio" value="43 "></label>Monthly
                backups with professional backup
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <br>

    <div id="weeklymsg">
        Weekly backup information
    </div>

    <div id="monthlymsg">
        Monthly backup information
    </div>
```

Comment: I obviously, really, appreciate the work you have done, but again, this doesn't want to work with WHMCS. It's really lame. The only thing which is happening, is that both DIV's start hidden, as the top of your code mentions, however clicking on any option doesn't result in the corresponding DIV showing up. I think it's somehow blocked or doesn't read it correctly. I will try a few other things in the mean time as well with your supplied code. I am sorry you did all of this work for nothing. I really don't understand why this will not work... :/

Comment: I think I might have found the problem! The problem is the class "iradio_square-blue", when I removed that "live" in Firefox, it works. Weird... I have to check that out. I will add tje javascript stuff related to it. Maybe you understand what's wrong or causing this?

Comment: Well it's indeed the 2 paragraphs of coding in the base.js file (which I have posted in my original post). Is there a workaround for this? So the DIV's will even work with this code? TY

Comment: i assument that  `increaseArea: '20%'` is going to provide some additional space for the DIV's , that means this is required in ur case.. But with having a complete picture if your code, it is bit difficult to suggest an alternative method ..

Comment: I created a new JSFiddle with more details, however I don't know if this proves to be more helpful? The updated JSFiddle is found here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hvmzjzf/2/